# insert Signature-Pad in Oracle database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, oracle, base64

I've got a problem with signature-pad: [GitHub signature-pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)

When my signature is too fat I can't save it in my database.

My field is in BLOB type. I store the signature in base64.

I insert the base64 signature like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, SIGNATURE) values (1, utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAADICAYAAADGFbfiAAAcaklEQVR4nO3dzYrdyB[...]AASUVORK5CYII=')));
```

This is an Oracle 11G database.

Do you have any solve or do you know how to reduce the picture quality or anything else which can reduce file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found !

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id, signature)
        VALUES (1, EMPTY_CLOB())
        RETURNING signature INTO :signature";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$clob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":signature", $clob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
$clob->save(base64_decode($mySignatyure);

oci_commit($conn);
```

And it's work.

One day of research just for that..